# Supress MediaRequestProtection errors at site level

Tags: media-library, site-configuration

I have a multisite setup in sitecore 9.1 and getting the below error on

> ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value

I know the reason for this error and Instead we want to suppress this for one website alone. All other websites should still report in logs. Is there any config/ setup for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your site to `sitecore/mediaLibrary/requestProtection/ignoreSites` config node.

By default in 9.1.0 that setting is in `App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config`

```
<sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
  <mediaLibrary>
    <requestProtection>
      <!--  IGNORE SITES
            Specifies a list of site names for which the media protection module should not sign image ULRs with a hash value. When
            Sitecore processes an incoming media request for these sites, it does not check if there is a valid hash value.
      -->
      <ignoreSites>
        <site name="shell"/>
        <site name="login"/>
        <site name="admin"/>
        <site name="service"/>
        <site name="scheduler"/>
        <site name="system"/>
        <site name="publisher"/>
      </ignoreSites>
```

Make sure you add your changes via Sitecore config patch file. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/"> 
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <mediaLibrary>
      <requestProtection>
        <ignoreSites>
          <site name="my-custom-site">
            <!-- I disabled media protection for my-custom-site-on-purpose -->
          </site>
        </ignoreSites>
      </requestProtection>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try this out.

Comment: I had added a patch config as said above and see it in showconfig

Comment: '<requestProtection patch:source="Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config">

<ignoreSites>
<site name="shell"/>
<site name="login"/>
<site name="admin"/>
<site name="service"/>
<site name="scheduler"/>
<site name="system"/>
<site name="publisher"/>
**<site name="<MYSITE>" patch:source="RequestProtection.config"/>**
</ignoreSites>
</requestProtection>'

But still getting the above error.